# Assembly function recognition

Tags: assembly, static-analysis

I want to ask what kind of function properties I could use to detect function at assembly level. I have already function blocks from static analysis and for example now user starts to reverse function and decides that it is used for calculating algorithm "A" and saves it...and from now I can compare all the functions with "A" properties and if I find something similar, with relatively high confidence, I can say to user that this function is probably calculating algorithm "A". Can I use for example flow graph, system calls, memory writes or something like that? Thanks for answers.

Comment: I think you will have really hard time even to recognize which part of function and how many times is executed, especially if you expect it to work over hand written assembly. Running it inside virtual machine and observing patterns of memory access + how data change may reveal some basic algorithms, maybe like sorting/etc, but IMO any ugly hand written assembly will change the machine state in single functions so much, that only "some mess" will be correct assessment of it's functionality. :) IMO you would have really hard time just to evaluate which paths get executed (NP problem).

Answer (score 1):

Hand written code is the big challenge, try to reverse engineer a standup arcade game from the early days...hand written assembly.

But take compiled code from today, much much easier to see function calls, the entry points all look about the same, have stack frame stuff up front, stack clean up at the end of a function with a return (or tail optimization so that might be tricky).

Not that every function is called more than once, but when you see a call (vs a branch/jump) assuming it is a function, esp if compiled code.  Is there a stack frame, follow all the code paths to the end in a stack cleanup and return (doesnt have to be a one to one match for entry point and return, some optimization may return from more than one place in the "function").

Some functions are small enough or optimized enough that there isnt a stack frame, depends on the architecture, compiler, code, etc.  So you really have to look at assembly call destinations and the follow the code paths to a return.  Unfortunately not all instruction sets are clean on this, take ARM for example, depending on how they interwork arm and thumb instructions a branch link which is a tell tell function call might instead be replaced by more than one instruction, save the return address and branch.  or as gcc is doing now it might branch link to code filled in by the linker at link time that then does the bx, but that trampoline is not really the "function" entry point, it is just a trampoline to the function.  Likewise the return from a function in arm if interworking thumb and arm can also be not as obvious a pop from the stack to a gpr then a bx to that gpr rather than a pop to lr. (only some architecture versions does the pop to lr support changing modes, and then you have to get the compiler to generate it).

At the end of the day the only thing you have at the machine code level is the function call instruction for that architecture and its return instruction.  Decompiling is a fun term to use, but if any optimization happened, then you simply cannot go backward, even without optimization the backward path wouldnt be that readable.  It is not going to help you much.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the assembly code and run it in an emulator or simulator, if you can, and there you can use tools, your own custom tools or others, to analyze, recognize and detect the functionality and algorithms.

If you have assembly code you could also try and produce C code from it and analyze the C code.

It can depend on your environment and your specific assembly dialect.

Comment: I cannot run it...but decompilation solution sounds interesting, but I cant imagine how comparing two C functions could be that much easier than at assembly level? what are the pros of this approach?

Comment: @Peter If you can't run the code then it will be difficult to test it. C has unit test frameworks e.g. the [check](https://libcheck.github.io/check/) framework. If I was going to solve a similar problem I would also look at formal verification where there are theoretical methods to prove that a program meets a certain specification, if you research how to verify a specification for a program. Maybe you can post some code or describe more detail and background about your environment and the actual code, or if you want to learn the theory I think that you can look at verifying a specification.